# If I request calendar week in the first week of the year with PHP, do I get 1 or 01 as number?

Tags: php

If I will run this code `date('W');` in the first calendar week of the year, will I get as output 1 or 01?

thanks

Comment: `echo date("W",strtotime("2021-01-05"));` and find out.

Comment: It would have been quicker to test it yourself than to create an account and write a question

Answer (score 0):

It will return as 01. It always returns 2 digits.